# Q_OBJECT in QT (undefined reference to vtable xxx)

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote a simple test as follow:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>

class Foo : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
};

class foo1
{
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
Foo f;
return a.exec();
}
```

Which gives me an error:

> error: undefined reference to `vtable for Foo':

However, when I change `Foo f` to `Foo f()`, it complies without any error.
So my question is what is the different between `f` and `f()`?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the parenthesis makes it a function declaration. No object is actually created, so the error doesn't happen.

```
Foo f; //declaration of variable of type Foo

Foo f(); //declaration of function taking no args and returning Foo
```

The `undefined reference to vtable for Foo` error is because you added a call to `Q_OBJECT` without running qmake again. Once it's run, the error should disappear.

Comment: I have tried cleaning project and running qmake again, but the error still came when I used Foo f

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused of the class extended QObject to be declared in main.cpp, so
just add the line **#include "main.moc"** before (or after) your main method.
But in the next time define a separate h/cpp-file for QObject extended classes.